# FFmpeg: How can I loop a single frame of video to cover the length of audio track

Tags: ffmpeg, vob

I have a VOB file holding an MPEG-2 video track with an AC-3 audio track. The video track of that VOB file consists of a single frame, which when played in a DVD player, holds that still frame until the audio track has finished.

How can I (with FFMPEG ideally), loop that frame to make a "normal" video track that lasts for the length of the audio track, rather than just a single frame?

```
ffmpeg version N-91999-g148a21611d Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20180813
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 19.101 / 56. 19.101
  libavcodec     58. 30.100 / 58. 30.100
  libavformat    58. 18.102 / 58. 18.102
  libavdevice    58.  4.103 / 58.  4.103
  libavfilter     7. 32.100 /  7. 32.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mpeg, from '.\SINGLEFRAME.VOB':
  Duration: 00:00:47.94, start: 0.336711, bitrate: 439 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 8000 kb/s, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:2: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
```

Comment: What's the output format supposed to be? Player?

Comment: @Gyan an MPEG-2 video track with AC-3 audio, same codecs as the input.